# OPE of Energy-Momentum tensor with Descendant Fields

Tags: operators, conformal-field-theory

In the book *Conformal Field Theory* by Di Francesco et al, the authors calculated the OPE (operator product expansion) of the energy momentum tensor $T(z)$ with the descendant field $\phi^{(-n)}$. There is one step in the derivation that confuses me: in eq 6.158, there is one term

$$
\begin{aligned}
    \sum_{l=0}^{n+1} \frac{2n-l}{(z-w)^{n-l+2}} \phi^{(-l)}(w)
    = \sum_{k=-1}^n \frac{n+k}{(z-w)^{k+2}} \phi^{(k - n)}(w)
    \qquad (k \equiv n - l)
\end{aligned}
$$

However, in the final result (6.160), the summation range of $k$ is *secretly changed* to

$$
\sum_{k=+1}^n \frac{n+k}{(z-w)^{k+2}} \phi^{(k - n)}(w)
$$

My question: **where do the $k=-1, 0$ terms go?**

Naively, one may think that these two terms

$$
\frac{n-1}{z-w} \phi^{(-n-1)}(w), \quad
\frac{n}{(z-w)^{2}} \phi^{(-n)}(w)
$$

are absorbed into the third term in eq. (6.160)

$$
\sum_{k \ge 0} (z-w)^{k-2} \phi^{(-k,-n)}(w)
$$

which contain two terms at the same order of singularity (at $k = 0, 1$)

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{(z-w)^2} \phi^{(0,-n)}(w) &= \frac{1}{(z-w)^2} (h+n) \phi^{(-n)}(w)
\\
\frac{1}{z-w} \phi^{(-1,-n)}(w) &= \frac{1}{z-w} \partial_w \phi^{(-n)}(w)
\end{aligned}
$$

But these results are not consistent. What's wrong?